# Finding a second solution for a differential equation with regular singular point

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

The differential equation: $xy'' + y =0$ has a regular singular point at $x=0$, using Frobenius' method, we get only one series solution which is:

$$ y_{1} (x) = x - \frac{1}{2} x^2 + \frac{1}{12} x^3 - \frac {1}{144} x^4 + \ldots$$

I'm trying to find the second solution $y_{2} (x)$ using the known equation:

$$y_{2} (x) = y_{1} (x) \int \frac {e^{- \int P(x) dx}}{(y_{1} (x))^{2}} dx$$

Then:
$$ y_{2} (x) = y_{1} (x) \int \frac {dx}{ \left(x - \frac{1}{2} x^2 + \frac{1}{12} x^3 - \frac {1}{144} x^4 + \ldots\right)^{2}}$$

My problem is dealing with $(x - \frac{1}{2} x^2 + \frac{1}{12} x^3 - \frac {1}{144} x^4 + ....)^{2}$ , how do I expand this? The expansion in my text gives $ (x^2 - x^3 + \frac{5}{12} x^4 - \frac {7}{72} x^5 +...)$ and then uses long division on it to give $ \frac {1}{x^2} + \frac {1}{x} + \frac {7}{12} + \frac {19}{72} x + ...$ to integrate term by term.

But I don't know how to expand that infinite squared bracket, can someone tell me how?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product